# Distribution of the minimum and maximum order statistics under a partial ordering

Tags: distributions, order-statistics

Let ${\bf{x}} = (x_{11},x_{12}, x_{13},\ldots,x_{nm})$ and $f({\bf{x}})\propto 1_A({\bf{x}}) \prod_{i,j} {x_{ij}}^{\alpha-1} (1-x_{ij})^{\beta-1}$  for $i = 1,\ldots, n$ and $j = 1, \ldots, m$.

That is, the joint distribution is proportional to the product of independent beta distributions, all with parameter $\alpha$ and $\beta$, truncated on set $A$.

where the set $A$ is the set of partial orders between these random variables so that $x_{ij} < x_{i, j+1}$ and $x_{ij} < x_{i+1, j}$.

From this, it follows that:
$0 < x_{11} < min(x_{12} , x_{21}$), and

$max(x_{m,n-1}, x_{n,m-1})< x_{mn} < 1$ and

$max(x_{i,j-1}, x_{i-1,j}) < x_{ij} < min(x_{i,j+1} , x_{i+1,j})$ for the rest.

Show that $x_{11}$ and $x_{mn}$ follows the distribution of the minimum and maximum order statistics of beta distribution for $m\times n$ samples, respectively. (I would be interested if anything more about the distribution of the rest of them can be shown as well.)

Comment: Could you please explain what it means to "enforce partial ordering" while the variables are *at the same time* declared to be "iid"?  The two conditions cannot both simultaneously hold, so evidently you are re-indexing them somehow. The partial ordering condition does not appear to uniquely determine the re-indexing, so exactly how is it done?

Comment: @whuber I edit the text. Is that clear now?

Comment: Yes, thank you.  All you need to do is observe $X_{11}$ is the smallest and $X_{mn}$ the largest of the variables and you're done.  There's nothing special about the Beta distribution apart from its continuity.

Comment: It seems obvious but I need a proof.